# Terraform copies but (cloud-init) doesn't run user_data script on Bitnami EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, bitnami, cloud-init

I'm trying to have Terraform run my bash script after deploying my Bitnami EC2 instance (AMI: `ami-0f185ef928bf37528`). I can find the file at `/var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts/part-001` but it isn't being run.

My desired script is a little more complicated but even this isn't being run:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
set -x
echo "Hello World.  The time is now $(date -R)!" | tee /root/output.txt
mkdir /opt/bitnami/projects
exit
```

main.tf contains

```
resource "aws_instance" "app_server" {
  ami             = "ami-0f185ef928bf37528"
  instance_type   = "t2.micro"
  key_name        = "app_server"
  security_groups = [aws_security_group.ec2_sg.name]
  user_data       = file("init.sh")
}
```

I'm not seeing any obvious issues or indicators in `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log` and `/var/log/cloud-init.log`

Comment: Which region is that? Amis are region specific.

Comment: @Marcin us-west-2

Comment: How did it go? Still does not work, even thought the code in the question is perfectly valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to replicate your issue, but your code **works perfectly**:

```
      ___ _ _                   _
      | _ |_) |_ _ _  __ _ _ __ (_)
      | _ \ |  _| ' \/ _` | '  \| |
      |___/_|\__|_|_|\__,_|_|_|_|_|
  
  *** Welcome to the Node.js packaged by Bitnami 17.8.0-2                 ***
  *** Documentation:  https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/infrastructure/nodejs/ ***
  ***                 https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/                       ***
  *** Bitnami Forums: https://community.bitnami.com/                      ***
bitnami@ip-172-31-37-75:~$ sudo su -
root@ip-172-31-37-75:~# ls
output.txt
root@ip-172-31-37-75:~# cat output.txt 
Hello World.  The time is now Sat, 02 Apr 2022 22:53:55 +0000!
root@ip-172-31-37-75:~# cd /opt/bitnami/
apache/       bncert/       common/       gonit/        node/         python/       scripts/      var/          
apache2/      bndiagnostic/ git/          nami/         projects/     redis/        stats/        
root@ip-172-31-37-75:~# cd /opt/bitnami/p
projects/ python/   
root@ip-172-31-37-75:~# cd /opt/bitnami/p
projects/ python/   
root@ip-172-31-37-75:~# cd /opt/bitnami/projects/
```

Thus its possible that your real code that you are using is different then in the question.

Comment: Maybe OP's user-data script contains carriage returns?

Comment: I'm not sure why it wasn't working for me. I ended up discovering that I could start the file with #cloud-boothook and it would run everytime.